# Windows 10 Explorer: Where are open window sizes & positions stored/saved?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Tired of Wind-X crashing and losing all of my open explorer windows. Because of the work I do, I generally end up with 10-15 explorer windows open (sometimes more). And anytime I crash, I lose my place with what I was doing.

Is there a registry location, saved state, or system settings file/folder that contains the explorer window data for the active state of explorer.exe?

On macOS Sierra, I know the data for Finder is in ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState. I managed to make a couple apps in automator: one to save a backup of the current Finder window positions, sizes, open tabs/locations, and another to quit Finder, restore the Finder windows from the most recent backup, and relaunch Finder. Hopefully, there is some way to do the same for Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Not any useful place. Windows Explorer changes its views on the fly and the views are not there the next time.  Windows Explorer has been like this for years.

If I wish a constant view (and I do most of the time) I use xPlorer2 (Zabkat) and it does this just great.

You can go into Explorer, View, Options, Change options and in the dialogue box that comes up, click the View tab and set Apply to all Folders.  This works for a while but certainly not permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the **`XP`** days, individual folders remembered their window size/position along with their other view settings, but  that is no longer the case.

**Explorer** only remembers the size/position of the last **Explorer** window closed. All others are lost.

That position in saved in the registry under:
**`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell`**

[image]